# Is it possible to call Print() without instantiating ChromiumWebBrowser in a form?

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

Is it possible?

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty);
browser.LoadHtml("<html goes here>", @"http://www.google.com/", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
browser.Print();
```

It throws an exception, but work fine when loaded into a form.

Comment: You've tagged WinForms and OffScreen, which are you using?

Comment: I removed the WinForms tag. I want to do this Offscreen

Comment: OffScreen is a separate Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen/ is that the package you are using? Or are you using CefSharp.Winforms?

Comment: I use the WinForms package, but I did realize there was an Offscreen package. Does that support loading html and open print dialog or print to pdf?

Comment: The OffScreen implementation uses the same underlying browser engine as the WPF implementation. You can print to PDF without displaying any output to the user. You can actually print as well though a print dialog will be displayed by default. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.OffScreen/Program.cs has a very simple set of examples.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is there a way to get access the print dialog?

Comment: What do you mean by get access the print dialog?

Comment: Open the printdialog as a dialog/format to get the buttons clicked(ok or cancel).

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/98.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_Print_1.htm